# MySQl v5.6 How to exclude unwanted / incorrect rows produced after Joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, mysql-5.6

I have two tables , I want to fetch correct data rows, but when I make a join in between incorrect extra rows are getting create. I want to exclude them.

Table T1

| Employee_ID | Work_START |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 10 Nov |
| 1111 | 14 Nov |
| 1111 | 18 Nov |

Table T2

| Employee_ID | Work_END |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 12 Nov |
| 1111 | 15 Nov |
| 1111 | 20 Nov |

I can not use Rank Function since **MySQL version is 5.6** and **I have Read access to DB** so can not create INDEX or use SET function

I tried to make a join with Below **SQL Query**:

```
Select T1.Employee_ID, T1.Work_START, T2.Work_END from T1

Left Join T2 On T1.Employee_ID = T2.Employee_ID

where T2.Work_END > T1.Work_START
```

(used this condition to reduce the incorrect joined rows)

I tried using Left , Right join, using Distinct function as well

I am getting the result as below

| Order_ID | Order_Date | Ship_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 10 Nov | 12 Nov |
| 1111 | 10 Nov | 15 Nov |
| 1111 | 10 Nov | 20 Nov |
| 1111 | 14 Nov | 15 Nov |
| 1111 | 14 Nov | 20 Nov |
| 1111 | 18 Nov | 20 Nov |

**Expected Result** is as below

**Logic of Output** : an employee has worked on a task on 3 different times, so to get those correct 3 rows I want the expected table to follow the below condition

row 1 work_END should be higher than row 1 Work_START and
2nd row Work_START should be higher than 1st row Work_END and so on
next row Work_start should be higher than previos row Work_END

**Expected Table**

| Order_ID | Order_Date | Ship_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 10 Nov | 12 Nov |
| 1111 | 14 Nov | 15 Nov |
| 1111 | 18 Nov | 20 Nov |

**Please Note: I Have read access to DB and Can not use Rank function since MySQL version is 5.6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer : you should consider fixing your data model. Spreading that data over two different tables does not look like appropriate design.

With the current data model, we could approach the question like so: starting from each beginning date in the first table, bring the closest end date with a subquery:

```
select t1.employee_id, t1.work_start,
    (
        select min(t2.work_end)
        from t2 
        where t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id and t2.work_end > t1.work_start
    ) work_end
from t1
```

This guarantees as many rows in the resultset as there are in the first table (not more, not less). If the dates of the two tables do not properly interleave, you might see results that look inconsistent somehow (using `row_number()` would not avoid this).

Comment: Hello GMB, It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

About data modeling, we have BIG DATA, and the columns I mentioned above were created for reference, although I have to derive the one column from one other table, its complicated.

Thank you so much for the help!